# problem for getting the memory leak in frame setting

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-leaks

I am implementing an iPhone app.for that,creating a common view controller throughout the application and i am changing my views according to the requirements. for that i am writing the code like

```
addViewController = [[ProAddViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProAddViewController" bundle:nil];
[addViewController.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
currentTabView = addViewController ;
```

and then when ever i want to add new view for the currentTabView, i am releasing  the previous one then adding new view controller's view to the currentTabView.finally i am releasing the currentTabView in dealloc().

i am getting a memory leak in the line shown below.

```
[addViewController.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
```

Can any one please help me out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is possible your loadView or viewDidLoad is leaking memory inside of your addViewController.

Comment: Can u post some more code? Want to know that whether u r releasing the addViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way can be, 
if you are using the `addViewController` and `currentTabView` in a view controller, then declare them as a property, and use, `self.addViewController` and `self.currentTabView` when assigning new values. 
Then compiler will automatically handle releasing and deallocating. surely you have to release them in dealloc.

```
    self.addViewController = [[ProAddViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ProAddViewController" 
bundle:nil];
    [addViewController.view setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
    self.currentTabView = addViewController ;
```